# Image PixelFormat causing AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, .net, image, image-processing

I am using the [Luxand Face SDK](https://www.luxand.com/facesdk/download/) for a simple test. My C# WinForms application is 32-bit and so is the referenced `FaceSDK.NET.dll`.

- Windows 10 1903
- Windows Forms Application
- .NET Framework 4.8
- 32-bit

The code simply creates a `Bitmap` object and tries to create a Luxand `CImage` object from it. Here is the code:

```
    private void ButtonDetect_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var pixelFormat = PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb;
        var luxandImageMode = Luxand.FSDK.FSDK_IMAGEMODE.FSDK_IMAGE_COLOR_32BIT;

        var bitmap = new Bitmap(100, 100, pixelFormat);
        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            graphics.Clear(Color.Yellow);
            graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, 10, 10, bitmap.Width - (10 * 2), bitmap.Height - (10 * 2));
        }

        var data = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bitmap.PixelFormat);
        var buffer = new byte [data.Stride * data.Height];
        Marshal.Copy(data.Scan0, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        bitmap.UnlockBits(data);

        var handle = 0;
        var result = 0;
        //result = Luxand.FSDK.LoadImageFromCLRImage(ref handle, bitmap);
        //result = Luxand.FSDK.LoadImageFromFile(ref handle, @"D:\Images\Test.png");
        result = Luxand.FSDK.LoadImageFromBuffer(ref handle, buffer, data.Width, data.Height, data.Stride, luxandImageMode);
    }
```

The code produces an `AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.`.

The last three lines ALWAYS produce this error no matter what combination of `PixelFormat` I use. It is strange that even loading various `Bitmaps/Jpegs/Pngs` image files also produces the same error.

Any advice would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:** Just for good measure, I also tried the following in vain (same result):

- 64-Bit
- Console Application
- LINQPad

Please note that the library needs to be activated: `Luxand.FSDK.ActivateLibrary(@"Activation Code");`

Comment: Looking at the SDK documentation, I can see that the `handle` you are passing in should be a `pointer to HImage for receiving the loaded image handle`. You are passing in 0 which doesn't seem to be the correct thing to do

Comment: @Martin, that is actually another overload that accepts an HBitmap Handle. The overloads above are documented clearly as well.

Comment: I even tried to create a `CImage` object directly passing a Bitmap in the constructor. Same result. Quite peculiar.

Comment: Drat, I was simply missing library initialization! `FSDK.InitializeLibrary();`. What a Simpson moment.

Comment: Which line causes the exception?